# How to set the extension and path for the output file in JetBrains File Watcher with Babel? [Linux]

Tags: babeljs, phpstorm, minify, jetbrains-ide, babel-cli

I am trying to set up PhpStorm to work with Babel instead of UglifyJS. I need the minifed output file to be written with **a different extension to the same directory** where the source script is located.

I changed argument line in the File Watchers settings for Babel to the following: `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --out-dir dist --out-file-extension .min.js --source-maps --presets minify`

This is works, but output file is saved to `/dist` directory (without specifying `--out-dir dist` everything stops working) and `--out-file-extension` option is completely ignored. I suspect this is due to the old version of Babel 6.2, which I can't manage to update.

This "Output paths to refresh" field changes also don't work: `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js`

Please explain how to change the arguments to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: OK .. so it's about "How to use Babel 6.2 from command line"; not about the actual PhpStorm's File Watcher. How do you run this babel command in your OS terminal? What command do you use?

Comment: **P.S.** *"This "Output paths to refresh" field changes also don't work"* This field is for  IDE to check those files for changes once current File Watcher finished running (e.g. to refresh target file; to upload it to remote server (if Deployment is configured in this way); to run File Watcher on it (if it has one) etc).

Comment: I seem to have found a solution. The arguments string should be like this:  `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --out-file $FileDirName$/$FileNameWithoutAllExtensions$.min.js --source-maps --presets minify`

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution works, which saves the output files .min.js at the same location, as the original file:

1. Install Babel global `sudo npm install --save-dev -g @babel/core`
2. Install Babel Minify global `sudo npm install babel-preset-minify --save-dev -g`
3. Setup PhpStorm Watcher with the following parameters:

**Programm:**

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js
```

**Arguments:**

```
$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --out-file $FileDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js --presets /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-preset-minify
```

[PhpStorm Watcher Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGJzl.png)